# Fluentd error log config file format RegEX

Tags: json, regex, ruby, parsing, fluentd

My error:

```
[warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "Oct  3 17:23:12 dc2prepzeebe03 broker[12925]: {\"severity\":\"DEBUG\",\"logging.googleapis.com/sourceLocation\":{\"function\":\"storeExporterPositions\",\"file\":\"ExporterPositionsDistributionService.java\",\"line\":44},\"message\":\"Received new exporter state {elasticsearch=194745449}\",\"serviceContext\":{\"service\":\"zeebe\",\"version\":\"development\"},\"context\":{\"threadId\":24,\"partitionId\":\"13\",\"threadPriority\":5,\"loggerName\":\"io.camunda.zeebe.broker.exporter\",\"threadName\":\"Broker-2-zb-fs-workers-0\",\"actor-name\":\"Broker-2-Exporter-13\"},\"timestampSeconds\":1696339392,\"timestampNanos\":45148621}"
```

my config file:

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/messages
  exclude_path /var/log/td-agent/td-agent.log
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/td-agent.pos
  tag dc-zeebe-tag
  read_from_head true
  format ^([^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) [^ ]* "(?<method>\S+) (?<path>[^ ]* +\S*)? (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*) (?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)")?
  refresh_intervals 60
  <parse>
    @type regex
    time_format %d:%H:%M:%S
  </parse>
</source>

<filter zeebe_log>
  @type parser
  key_name log_entry
  reserve_data true
  <parse>
    @type regex
    time_format %d:%H:%M:%S
  </parse>
</filter>
```

How can solve this problem? I want to show the correct output on Elasticsearch.

Comment: I'm probably not right, but your time_format doesn't appear to match the format of the times/dates in the log files. "%b %e %H:%M:%S" looks closer to your format.

Comment: Appears same error. I already checked the time format problem is not on this side in my opinion I made a mistake in the source config section.